Application Insights - Render timechart with two queries
I've got a query that renders a timechart like so. However, how can I also plot on the same graph where customDimensions.["Is Successful"] == "True"?
customEvents
    | extend TimeStamp = timestamp
    | where name contains 'Transaction Posted' and customDimensions.['Transaction Number'] != ''
    | where customDimensions.["Is Successful"] == "False"
    | make-series Total=count() on TimeStamp from (startofday(now()) - 7days) to now() step 1d
    | project-reorder TimeStamp, Total
    | render timechart


Update:


I´ve posted an idea. Please check it out.

Could I help you out. Or do you need anything else?

You could do something like this:
customEvents
    | where timestamp >= ago(7d)
    | extend Product = tostring(customDimensions.["Is Successful"])
    | extend TransactionNumber = tostring(customDimensions.["Transaction Number"])
    | extend StoreCode = tostring(customDimensions.["StoreCode"])
    | extend TillNumber = tostring(customDimensions.["TillNumber"])
    | extend TimeStamp = timestamp
    | extend Success = tostring(customDimensions.["Is Successful"])
    | where name contains 'Transaction Posted' and customDimensions.['Transaction Number'] != ''
    | summarize count() by Success, bin(Timestamp, 1d)
    | render timechart

With render timechart:

With render columnchart:

Success has to be transformed to a string, otherwise it won´t work.

Fyi, I've simplified the original post. Your suggestion kind of works however, the x axis doesn't have a timeframe. I would like it from now to the last 7 days.

I´ve improved my query. Please check it out. But as you can see on my screenshot, there should be a timeframe on the x-axis.

Thanks, that sort of works however when there isn't a count, it doesn't default to 0.

If there are no unsuccessfull ones in a certain timeframe, than the line isn´t displayed at all, yes.

And it does default to 0, when there are matches on a later timeframe. Then the line will be connected from the 0-line to the new values. As you can see on my screenshot (red line).

I've updated my original post, if you look at False between Jun 17 to Jun 20, there are no 0 values when there should have been and so that shouldn't have been connected with a straight line.

I see your point. I think with render timechart that is not possible. You could try: render columnchart. That looks better, even for timeframes where you have no values.

But this connection-behaviour with a straight line is the same, like in your first post with one True or False value. Its just the plotting behaviour.

Added another screenshot for render columnchart
